# How to prevent a jQuery click function from targeting other elements in DOM as well?

Tags: jquery, click, accordion, addclass

I'm trying to implement an accordion with jQuery - but not using that dedicated plugin, rather realizing it by a click function that can be done with the standard jQuery library:

Script:

```
jQuery('.abhandlungen h4').click(function(){
    if(false == jQuery(this).next('p').is(':visible')) {jQuery('p').slideUp(8); jQuery(this).parent().addClass("pressed");}
    if(true  == jQuery(this).next('p').is(':visible')) {jQuery(this).parent().removeClass("pressed");}
        jQuery(this).next('p').slideToggle(240);
        jQuery(this).parent().siblings('li').removeClass("pressed");
});
```

Markup:

```
<div id="nav" class="navigation">
    <div class="nav-previous"><p><a href="#" rel="prev">Link to previous page</a></p></div>
    <div class="nav-next"><p><a href="#" rel="next">Link to next page</a></p></div>
</div>
<div class="post">
    <ul class="abhandlungen">
        <li>
            <h4><span class="icon"></span>Title of expandable section 1</h4>
            <p>Copy text to appear by clicking on the above h4</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h4><span class="icon"></span>Title of expandable section 2</h4>
            <p>Copy text to appear by clicking on the above h4</p>
        </li>
        <!-- and further ones -->
    </ul>
</div>
```

Now I have the problem, that my clicks on an h4 also will trigger my navigation line to disappear. Could there be any dependencies on my `rel=prev` and `rel=next` in navigation?

Plus I wonder about the strange behaviour that the very first click of each makes its siblings visible but not adds the class `.pressed`. All further clicks just work as expected. Maybe you can help me by watching this jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/xfSya/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
jQuery('p').slideUp(8);
```

to:

```
jQuery('p',this).slideUp(8);
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/xfSya/2/)**

Your original selector was targeting all paragraph tags which caused the links to disappear.

Comment: One further question to this: My concept was to keep open only 1 container at time (so the open one closes by clicking another). Could that also be realized this way?

Comment: Yes, that's definitely possible, however I suggest you open a new question if you need help with that.